# Getting GitHub and Gerrit to play nicely

Tags: git, repository, github, gerrit

I host a private repo on [GitHub](http://github.com). I also want to use [Gerrit](http://gerrit.googlecode.com), particularly for the [Hudson Gerrit Trigger plugin](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Gerrit+Trigger). AFAICT, there isn't any simple solution for using them together.

I'd appreciate any help on any of the following wants.

---

## What I want

- Clone GitHub repo and add to Gerrit's projects either:

  1. [manually](http://gerrit.googlecode.com/svn/documentation/2.1.5/project-setup.html#manual_creation), or
  2. [during `init`](http://gerrit.googlecode.com/svn/documentation/2.1.5/install.html#project_setup)
- Merge changes with GitHub using Gerrit

---

## What I've tried

### Cloning/Adding...

**Manually**: I clone the repo as normal, then add into `H2` like so:

```
INSERT INTO projects
(use_contributor_agreements,submit_type,name)
VALUES
('N','M','new/Repo');
```

**During `init`**:

```
*** Git Repositories
***

Location of Git repositories   [git]: git@github.com:YourName/Repo.git
```

I don't think that's correct.

---

## What happens

### Cloning/Adding...

**Manually**:

I get this error: `repository not found: Cannot open repository Repo`

**During `init`**:

Creates the directory at `~/gerrit2/git@github.com:YourName/Repo.git` and sub-directory `Repo.git`, which itself contains an empty `Git` repo. Not exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 3):

Not try myself, but you could use gerrit repo and **[mirror](http://gerrit.googlecode.com/svn/documentation/2.1.5/config-replication.html)** to github

Answer (score 1):

**Gerrit is built on top of JGit which does not support a remote GitHub repository.**

JGit itself allows to either have the repository on your local (or shared) filesystem or to have it accessible through a genefic "DFS" (Distributed File System) provider.
See as reference: [JGit : connect to distant repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10311857/jgit-connect-to-distant-repository).

I wrote an article on a different strategy to use Gerrit and GitHub together: http://www.packtpub.com/article/using-gerrit-with-github

In a nutshell you can delegate three different tasks to GitHub:

1. Authentication: Gerrit request a GitHub login using OAuth 2.0 authentication API
2. Pull requests: Gerrit can fetch GitHub pull requests and present them as Gerrit changes
3. Replication: Gerrit can push back the changes (either in review or merged) to GitHub

**NOTE:** Once you start using Gerrit as your gateway to GitHub, you SHOULD NOT push directly to GitHub anymore but rely on either Pull Requests (imported to Gerrit) or directly pushing to Gerrit and working through changes review.

If you want to experiment Gerrit and GitHub integrated in this way, you can check out http://gerrithub.io, which is essentially a Gerrit 2.9-SNAPSHOT with the GitHub plugin configured as before.

Luca.